# HTML5 data attributes lost in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I have a jQueryUI modal which loads its content based on HTML5 data attributes:

```
<button id="add-dates-button" name="add-dates-button" href="#" class="dialog-ajax-form" data-table="jto-dates-add" data-title="Add Job" data-id="<?=$jto_id?>">Add Date(s)</button>
```

With the following (partial) script triggered by the click of the button, I get the variables in FF to print to console just fine. However, in Safari, they all post undefined:

```
$(document).on('click','.dialog-ajax-form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var targete = $(e.target);
    var tbl = $(e.target).data('table');
    var id = $(e.target).data('id');
    var title = $(e.target).data('title');
    console.log(title);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(targete);
    console.log(tbl);
```

If I access the attributes in Safari with the following, however, I can get the value:

```
console.log( document.getElementById('add-dates-button').getAttribute( 'data-table' ) );
```

I use the dialog-ajax-form script in a variety of places, so accessing the variable this specifically is not ideal. Can anyone explain why I'm losing these values in Safari?

Comment: @dandavis there is HTML5 `data-*` support; https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: @DaveAnderson: i said for "setting data- attribs", which i stand by... that said, i misread it, and he's not setting...

Comment: @dandavis, aren't the attributes already set in the button itself? My understanding of .data() was that I could access the data- attributes.

Using .attr("data-name") has the same result.

Comment: yes, i was mistaken in my first (deleted) comment. look close, i don't see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the `$(e.target)` element is the button in Safari? Your selector `.dialog-ajax-form` is not specific to the `<button id="add-dates-button">` element but I assume this is contained within the form.

You need to get find the element with the attribute, perhaps use:

```
var $target = $(e.target);
var tbl = $target.data('table') || $target.find('[data-table]').data('table');
```

This will use the attribute for `$(e.target)` if it has it otherwise look for children with the attribute.

Comment: Could also adjust selector to `$(document).on('click','#add-dates-button'`

Comment: @guest271314 unsure if there are multiple buttons in different forms with the same `data-*` attributes.

Comment: It turns out in Safari the e.target is pegging off a <span> element

Comment: In follow-up, in lieu of the $(e.target), however, I altered the code to utilize $(this), which solved the problem.e